# MSSQL 2008: Connection string error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

In my config.properties I have:

```
url = jdbc:sqlserver://ABC\SQLSERVER2008:1433;databasename=M4E;username=sa;password=123456
driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

but it doesn't properly connect to the DB. I get the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host ABCSQLSERVER2008, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null.
>   Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

When I debug, it appears ABCSQLSERVER2008, not ABC\SQLSERVER2008 as I expect.

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
url = jdbc:sqlserver://ABC\\SQLSERVER2008:1433;databasename=M4E;username=sa;password=123456
```

Comment: it's not about the url, i got the problem, just edit the SQL Server Network Configuration. Insert TCP Port 1433 into IPAII in TCP/IP.

Comment: @user2204183 then you should have asked the right question. I think the answer here seems to fit perfectly for the question you have asked. You should accept this as the answer.